# how to compare values in array in while loop

Tags: php, arrays

My while loop condition looks like this:

```
while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif) 
{
.....thing to be done
}
```

Now instead of comparing between two values, I compare between array and a string.

The array look like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["time"]=>
    int(1473735528)
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["time"]=>
    int(1473507326)
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
}
```

And

```
$lastmodif = 1473503210;
```

> So how do I compare if any value of key called `time` in the given array is greater
>   than `$lastmodif` in while loop?

Comment: you don't need while loop you can use foreach with if..else...endif

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @siddhesh's comment, foreach will loop through your array just fine.

```
foreach($yourarray as $item) {
  if($item['time'] <= $lastmodif) {
     // do your work
  }
}
```

This loop goes through your array and giving you a copy of each item.
If you want to *modify* the items, you need to use the reference:

```
foreach($yourarray as &$item) {      // <-- notice the &
  if($item['time'] <= $lastmodif) {
    // do your work
  }
}
```